# Mapbox select pin listener

Tags: android, mapbox

How to get listener for [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/) pin. I want to change the drawable icon when I tap on the marker.

```
Marker marker = new Marker(myMapBoxView,title, details, new LatLng(latitude,longitude));
                marker.setIcon(new Icon(myDrawable)));
```

If I will tap this marker I will want to change the drawable. What is the listener to get this action.

Thank you!

Comment: there's not enough details to answer your question

Comment: I complete my question with an example marker code that I will want to change his drawable Icon.Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spend almost one day to find it. If somebody have same problem you can find the listener here:

```
myMapBoxView.setMapViewListener(new MapViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShowMarker(MapView mapView, Marker marker) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onHideMarker(MapView mapView, Marker marker) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTapMarker(MapView mapView, Marker marker) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPressMarker(MapView mapView, Marker marker) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTapMap(MapView mapView, ILatLng iLatLng) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPressMap(MapView mapView, ILatLng iLatLng) {

            }
        });
```